# custom jquery plugin function error calling second time on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem when clicking an Item the second time with the same class and it consoles out with an error toggle2classes is not a function so why is this happening.

the first class with .toggle-form class:

```
<a class="toggle-form panel-btn" href="#" title="Create A New Product">C<span></span></a>

$(function() {

    $.fn.toggle2classes = function(class1, class2){
        if( !class1 || !class2 )
            return this;

        return this.each(function(){
            var $elm = $(this);

            if($elm.hasClass(class1) || $elm.hasClass(class2) )
                $elm.toggleClass(class1 +' '+ class2);
            else
                $elm.addClass(class1);
      });
    };

     $('.toggle-form').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.form-content').toggle2classes('animate-form-in', 'animate-form-out');
    });
});
```

second item with .toggle-form class:

```
<div class="panel-content form-content">
    <div class="form">
        <h1><span class="panel-symbol" href="#" title="Back To Products">C<span><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span>Create Products</h1>
        <button class="toggle-form">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).toggle2classes is not a function
```

Comment: You sure you included the jquery source? https://jsfiddle.net/o66hge9r/

Comment: @Dekel If he didn't, it would error on `$(function...)`

Comment: Is it possible you loaded jQuery twice? That often causes problems like this.

Comment: @Barmar not so true, other libs use `$` almost the same as jquery, so it might be that the `$(function..)` will be correct syntax but the `$(...).toggle2classes` wont

Comment: @Dekel Most other uses of `$` just use it to look up an ID, not a selector. And `$(function...)` is very jQuery-specific.

Comment: @Dekel Also `.on()` worked, that's jQuery. And `$.fn.toggleclasses` worked.

Comment: I agree, but did you check my jsfiddle? It works great :)

Comment: It was because I had two jquery files sorry guys